# Use case of each_with_index vs index in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

New to Ruby; When I am working with arrays, is there a difference between `Enumerable#each_with_index` and `Array#index` I have been working with a multidimensional array in which I am trying to find the location of a given value. My code is able to pass all the tests when I use either one. Coordinates is the array I am using to hold the location of the given value (in this case 1)

```
field=[[1,0],[0,0]]
coordinates=[]  
field.each_with_index do |item|
  if item.index(1)
    coordinates.push(field.index(item)).push(item.index(1))
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your code:

```
field=[[1,0],[0,0]]
coordindates = []  
field.each_with_index do |item|
  if item.index(1)
    coordinates.push(field.index(item)).push(item.index(1))
  end
end
```

Let:

```
enum = field.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[1, 0], [0, 0]]:each_with_index>
```

As you see this returns an enumerator.

Ruby sees your code like this:

```
enum.each do |item|
  if item.index(1)
    coordinates.push(field.index(item)).push(item.index(1))
  end
end
```

The elements of the enumerator will be passed into the block by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), which will call [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) since the receiver, `field` is an instance of the class `Array`.

We can see the elements of `enum` by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[1, 0], 0], [[0, 0], 1]]
```

As you see, it has two elements, each being an array of two elements, the first being an array of two integers and the second being an integer.

We can simulate the operation of `each` by sending [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to `enum` and assigning the block variables to the value returned by `next`. As there is but one block variable, `item`, we have:

```
item = enum.next
  #=> [[1, 0], 0]
```

That is quite likely neither what you were expecting nor what you wanted.

Next, you invoke [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) on `item`:

```
item.index(1)
  #=> nil
```

`index` searches the array `item` for an element that equals `1`. If it finds one it returns that element's index in the array. (For example, `item.index(0) #=> 1`). As neither `[1,0]` nor `0` equals `1`, `index` returns `nil`.

Let's rewind (and recreate the enumerator). You need two block variables:

```
field.each_with_index do |item, index|...
```

which is the same as:

```
enum.each do |item, index|...
```

So now:

```
item, index = enum.next
      #=> [[1, 0], 0] 
item  #=> [1, 0] 
index #=> 0
```

and

```
item.index(1)
  #=> 0
```

I will let you take it from here, but let me mention just one more thing. I'm not advocating it, but you could have written:

```
field.each_with_index do |(first, second), index|...
```

in which case:

```
(first, second), index = enum.next
       #=> [[1, 0], 0] 
first  #=> 1
second #=> 0 
index  #=> 0
```

Comment: ++ maybe your next answer can include some flossing examples **^,,,^**

Answer (score 1):

See Ruby doc: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index

`index` is a method of `Array`, it detects whether an item exists in a specific `Array`, return the index if the item exists, and `nil` if does not exist.

`each_with_index` is a method of `Enumerable` mixin, it usually takes 2 arguments, first one is item and the second one is index.

So your sample could be simplified as:

```
field = [[1, 0], [0, 0]]
coordinates = []
field.each_with_index do |item, index|
  item_index = item.index(1)
  coordinates << index << item_index if item_index
end
puts coordinates.inspect # => [0, 0]
```

Note your `field.index(item)` is just `index`.

Answer (score 1):

`Array#index` and `Enumerable#each_with_index` are not related whatsoever (functionally speaking), one is used to get the index of an object within an Array and the other one is used to walk through a collection.

Actually `each_with_index` is a mutation of the `each` method that additionally yields the index of the actual object within the collection. This method is very useful if you need to keep track of the current position of the object you are in. It saves you the trouble of creating and incrementing an additional variable.

For example

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].each_with_index do|char, idx|
     puts "#{idx}) #{char}"
end
```

output:

```
0) a
1) b
2) c
3) d
```

Without `each_with_index`

```
idx = 0
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].each do|char|
     puts "#{idx}) #{char}"
     idx += 1
end
```

output:

```
0) a
1) b
2) c
3) d
```

To find the index of an object within a multidimensional Array you will have to iterate at least through all the rows of the matrix, like this (using `each_with_index` and `index`)

```
def find_position(matrix, obj)
     matrix.each_with_index do|row, i|
          return [i, j] if j = row.index(obj)
     end
     return nil
end
```

for example:

```
find_position([[2,3],[4,5]], 5)  #  => [1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that:

```
fields = [[1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Enumerable#each_with_index passes each index as well as each object to the block:

```
fields.each_with_index do |field, idx|
  puts "#{field}, #{idx}"
end

#=> [1, 0], 0
#=> [0, 0], 1
```

Array#index returns the index of the matching array element:

```
puts fields.index([1, 0])

#=> 0
```